# How to pass an array to function

Tags: php

I have `$array = ["banana", "kiwi", "apple"];`

I want to pass it to `myFunction()` so that I can use it in that function. I did some search, and found `global` but it's not working.

```
   function myFunction() {
        global $array;
        foreach ($array as $k=> $path) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context of your code, you probably just need to use

```
myFunction($array);
```

and modify your function

```
function myFunction ($array) {
    ...
}
```

Have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array to a function the same way you do pass other types of variables.

```
$array = ["banana", "kiwi", "apple"];;

function myFunction($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $path) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}

myFunction($array);
```

For associative arrays, you will get the keys in the $k variable, otherwise, $k will be the numerical indexes.

Comment: I need to put that array from outside to use inside that function. as I see in your answer. I can't see my array? I mean I created that array outside the function. and I want to use it inside the function.

Comment: That's because I didn't call the function. I have modified the answer to include the line that calls the function and pass the array to it.